# CEC wake up command

Tags: boot, raspbmc, hdmi

When I boot my Raspberry my TV gets woken up over CEC.

Is there a way to send the wake up signal using shell so I could use cronjob to start my TV every morning at 7, for example?

Comment: I don't have any CEC devices so I can't test this by myself but `cec-client` from `libcec` seems to implement what you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm using Raspbian “wheezy”.

#### Setup

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install gcc autoconf libtool pkg-config libselinux1-dev liblockdev1-dev gawk g++ c++ libgudev-1.0-dev libudev-dev;

mkdir -p $HOME/distr/libcec; 
wget -P $HOME/distr/libcec https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/archive/master.zip;
unzip $HOME/distr/libcec/master.zip -d $HOME/distr/libcec/;
cd $HOME/distr/libcec/libcec-master;
./bootstrap;
./configure --with-rpi-include-path=/opt/vc/include --with-rpi-lib-path=/opt/vc/lib --enable-rpi;
make;
sudo make install;
sudo apt-get install cec-utils;
```

#### Usage

Use `echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s` to turn TV off and `echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s` to turn in on.

You may also have to substitute `/usr/local/bin/cec-client` for `cec-client` (or reconfigure your `PATH`) if the first one doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
echo 'on 0'|cec-client -s -d 1
```

is problematic, because it turns the TV on, but **ALSO** sets Raspberry Pi as the active source. It seems that the only way of changing the source to TV internal tuner is using JointSPACE framework for my Philips TV. I have unsuccessfully tried several different CEC command combinations to activate internal tuner. It is possible to switch between HDMI sources with CEC, but I have yet to discover how to switch to internal tuner...

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar, the command `echo 'on 0'|cec-client -s -d 1` only turns on the tv, I was curious if there is a single command to turn on tv and switch input to what the pi is on. I was also curious if its possible to run this at boot?

ANSWERED: (I answered the above, added to etc/rc.local to run at boot.) Still curious why single command does not work. Any Ideas?

```
echo 'on 0'|cec-client -s <- Turn on TV
echo 'as'|cec-client -s <- Initiate input Pi is active on
```

Yet the command to run both only gets me power. Not to big of a deal as I just run both at boot, but curious why the combined one isn't working.